# For unix screen terminal how to increase log?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

The output of my program being too long, on running it in screen terminal some part of output gets truncated.
To avoid this how can I increase log limit of screen terminal?
Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe try redirecting output to a file? Such as 

./myprog < out.txt

Comment: @squiguy - Did you mean: `./myprog > out.txt` instead?

Comment: Yes, essentially just redirecting the output! I got mixed up unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

this depends on the terminal you are actually using.

e.g. for the `xfce4-terminal`, go to "Edit->Settings->General->Scrollback" and change the scroll-buffer to your likings.

for kde's `konsole`, go to "Settings->Configure current Profile...->Scrolling->Fixed number of lines"

the classical `xterm` can be configured with a startup-flag  `-sl 777` (for 777 lines of scroll-back buffer) or via the `saveLines` config.

given that there are quite a number of terminals out there, you might want to check the manpages for the one you are using...:-)

Answer (score 1):

To increase the scrollback buffer for `GNU screen` (I assume this is what you are using from your question), start it with `screen -h <buffer_size>`.  Unfortunately, it appears the scrollback buffer cannot be resized after startup.

To set a new default scrollback buffer in `GNU screen`, add `defscrollback <num_lines>` to your `~/.screenrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are already using a screen session, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then type  `:scrollback #`, where # is the number of scrollback lines you would like.

At startup, you can use the -h argument as recommended above.